# Wrong result of multiplication: Undefined behavior or compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, undefined-behavior, compiler-bug

## Background

While debugging a problem in a numerical library, I was able to pinpoint the first place where the numbers started to become incorrect. However, the C++ code itself seemed correct. So I looked at the assembly produced by Visual Studio's C++ compiler and started suspecting a compiler bug.

## Code

I was able to reproduce the behavior in a strongly simplified, isolated version of the code:

sourceB.cpp:

```
double alwaysOneB(double a[3]) {
    return 1.0;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

__declspec(noinline)
bool alwaysTrue() {
    return true;
}

__declspec(noinline)
double alwaysOneA(const double a[3]) {
    return 1.0;
}

double alwaysOneB(double a[3]); // implemented in sourceB.cpp

int main() {
    double* result = new double[2];

    if (alwaysTrue()) {
        double v[3];
        v[0] = 0.0;
        v[1] = 0.0;
        v[2] = 0.0;

        alwaysOneB(v);

        double d = alwaysOneA(v); // d = 1

        std::cout << "d = " << d << std::endl; // output: "d = 1" (as expected)

        result[0] = d * v[2];
        result[1] = d * d; // should be: 1 * 1 => 1 
    }
    if (alwaysTrue()) {
        std::cout << "result[1] = " << result[1] << std::endl; // output: "result[1] = 2.23943e-47" (expected: 1)
    }

    delete[] result;
    return 0;
}
```

The code contains some bogus calls to other functions that are (unfortunately) necessary to reproduce the problem. However, the expected behavior should still be pretty clear. A value of `1.0` is assigned to the variable `d`, which is then multiplied by itself. That result should again be `1.0`, which is written to an array and printed to the console. So the desired output is:

```
d = 1
result[1] = 1
```

However, the obtained output is:

```
d = 1
result[1] = 3.77013e+214
```

## Test Environment

The code was tested with the C++ compiler that comes with Visual Studio Community 2019 (latest update, VS 16.11.9, VC++ 00435-60000-00000-AA327). The problem only occurs **with optimizations activated (`/O2`)**. Compiling with `/Od` produces a binary that prints the correct output.

In the reduced example (not for the original problem when compiling the full library) I also had to **deactivate "Full Program Optimization"**, otherwise the compiler gets rid of my bogus function calls.

This reduced example only reproduces the problem when compiled for **`x86`** (other examples reproduce the problem for **`x64`**).

The full compilation command line is as follows:
`/permissive- /ifcOutput "Release\" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\DecimateBug2.pch" /diagnostics:column`

Full Visual Studio solution to download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EyoX0uXEkvfJ_Fh649k9XjJQPdDUMik7/view?usp=sharing

Both the GNU compiler and Clang produce binaries that print the desired result.

## Question

Is there any undefined behavior in this code that I am unable to see and that justifies an incorrect result? Or should I report this as a compiler bug?

## Assembly produced by the compiler

For the two multiplication lines

```
        result[0] = d * v[2];
        result[1] = d * d;
```

the compiler produces the following assembly code:

```
00CF1432  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [esp+18h]   // Load d into first part of xmm1
00CF1438  unpcklpd    xmm1,xmm1                   // Load d into second part of xmm1
00CF143C  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [esp+30h]  // Load second operands into xmm0
00CF1441  mulpd       xmm0,xmm1                   // 2 multiplications at one
00CF1445  movups      xmmword ptr [esi],xmm0      // store result
```

Apparently it tries to perform the two multiplications at once using `mulpd`. In the first two lines it successfully loads the `d` operand into both parts of the `xmm1` register (as first operands). But when it tries to load both second operands (`v[2]` and `d`), it simply loads 128 bits from the `v[2]` address (`esp+30h`). That's fine for the second operand of the *first* multiplication (`v[2]`), but not for the *second* multiplication (with `d`). Apparently the code supposes that `d` is located immediately after `v` in memory. However, it isn't. The variable `d` is never actually stored in memory, it seems to exist only in registers.

This makes me strongly suspect a compiler bug. However, I wanted to confirm that I am not missing any undefined behavior that justifies the incorrect assembly.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see anything suspicious in the code. The behavior is well-defined, far as I can tell. Looks like a codegen bug to me, too.

Comment: @Martin I can not reproduce.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: When stating that you cannot reproduce a suspected compiler bug, you may want to mention which version of the compiler you are using.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I used Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA438

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Interesting. How can I get AA438? I am on AA327 and the VS updater doesn't offer any updates.

Comment: @Martin I am using the Community edition. It is updated automatically.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I use Community, too, fully updated. Anyway, I forgot to mention that in the reduced example I deactivated "Whole Program Optimization". Will edit the question.

Comment: FWIW I also *can't* reproduce with Community edition 00435-60000-00000-AA785, with a default project but whole program optimization disabled.

Comment: @HerrJoebob Hmm, weird. You are the second person who cannot reproduce it. I've uploaded a VS solution - maybe I'm missing something? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EyoX0uXEkvfJ_Fh649k9XjJQPdDUMik7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried the `DecimalBug2.zip` solution on Visual Studio Community 2019, v 16.11.8, and could confirm the bug.

Comment: I tested your newly uploaded code on VS2022, and there is no problem you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though nobody posted an answer, from the comment section I could conclude that:

- Nobody found any undefined behavior in the bug repro code.
- At least some of you were able to reproduce the undesired behavior.

So I filed [a bug report against Visual Studio 2019](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wrong-result-of-multiplication-in-Visual/1646585).

The Microsoft team confirmed the problem.

However, unfortunately it seems like Visual Studio 2019 will ***not*** receive a bug fix because Visual Studio 2022 seemingly does not have the bug. Apparently, the most recent version not having that particular bug is good enough for Microsoft's quality standards.

I find this disappointing because I think that the correctness of a compiler is essential and Visual Studio 2022 has just been released with new features and therefore probably contains new bugs. So there is no real "stable version" (one is cutting edge, the other one doesn't get bug fixes). But I guess we have to live with that or choose a different, more stable compiler.

Comment: You cannot claim anything for a software that is free, and Microsoft offers you a solution. So why worry ?

Think about the numerous other bugs that are there waiting for you to discover them and that are... undocumented.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: "Numerous other bugs [...] that are undocumented" - that's exactly the point. In order for those bugs to be fixed, someone has to find them. That takes time and users' legwork (like mine in this bug report). If you don't maintain a branch that receives only fixes and no new features, there will never be a really stable version. By the time people discover their bugs and are willing to do some analysis, Microsoft has moved on to new versions with shiny new bugs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: About VC++ being free: I'm not claiming anything (even though the same compiler is used in payment versions of VS). In fact, I don't care much at all about this particular bug. Now that I have identified the problem, I can apply a very simple workaround. I'm just mentioning that these quality standards don't inspire trust. That makes me worry in general about the Microsoft tool chain.

Comment: How do yo want to document undiscovered bugs ??? By the way, I haven't seen a code generation bug with VS since 20 years or so.